# Setting focus in JOptionPane JPasswordField

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have created a password field using `JOptionPane`. When I run the program, the `JOptionPane` comes up and looks great, however the focus always goes to the OK button. I want the focus start on the password field. I've tried `requestFocus()`, `requestFocusInWindow()`, but this doesn't seem to work. Is there something special that I need to go to get the focus on password field?

See my code below :

```
JPasswordField pf = new JPasswordField();
pf.requestFocusInWindow();
int okCxl = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, pf, "ENTER SUPERUSER PASSWORD", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set focus on specific JTextfield inside JOptionPane when created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478394/how-to-set-focus-on-specific-jtextfield-inside-joptionpane-when-created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create an instance of the [`JOPtionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) and use the [`setWantsInput(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#setWantsInput%28boolean%29) method.  It's not as convenient, but the builder methods you're using are really just for the basic cases.  Then you'll need to add a [`ComponentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) to the Dialog to request selection of your password field. You can find more similar documenation on the [`JOptionPane` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).

```
    final JPasswordField pf = new JPasswordField();
    //Create OptionPane & Dialog
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(pf, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog("ENTER SUPERUSER PASSWORD");
    //Add a listener to the dialog to request focus of Password Field
    dialog.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener(){

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            pf.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
        @Override public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}
        @Override public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {}
        @Override public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}
        });

    dialog.setVisible(true);
```