# How do I request focus on a JPasswordField inside a JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

[I've learned in this other question that it's possible by overriding the addNotify method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478394/how-to-set-focus-on-specific-jtextfield-inside-joptionpane-when-created), but that's not working. Here's my code:

```
private boolean accessPasswordFrame(String titleText, String labelText, String errorMessage, int accessType) {
    JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField() {
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            requestFocus();
        }
    };
    final JComponent[] inputs = new JComponent[] {
        new JLabel(labelText),
        passwordField
    };
    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, inputs, titleText, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        String rootPass = new String(passwordField.getPassword());
        if (accessType == ADMIN_TYPE) {
            if (rootPass.equals(ROOT_PASSWORD)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        errorMessage, "Erro",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } else if (accessType == USER_TYPE) {
            if (PasswordFrame.getPasswords() != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : PasswordFrame.getPasswords().entrySet()) {
                    if (rootPass.equals(e.getValue())) {
                        lastUser = e.getKey();
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                errorMessage, "Erro",
                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Usuários cadastrados não existem.", "Erro",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Once the JOptionPane appears, the default focus is on the "Ok" button:

[image]

And if I just `requestFocus()` before showing the dialog, it doesn't work as well.

Comment: `but that's not working.` - so did you try the other suggestions in that link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a listener to the component so that the listener is invoked when the option pane is made visible and you can then request focus on the component.

Check out `RequestFocusListener` class found in [Dialog Focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) for a reusable solution.

Comment: That `.addAncestorListener(new RequestFocusListener());` worked like a charm, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Provided solutions didn't work for me. Following code worked in my case:

```
    passwordField.setFocusable(true);
    passwordField.requestFocusInWindow();
    passwordField.setCaretPosition(0);
```

note that **JFrame which contains password field has to be visible** before calling `.requestFocusInWindow()`