# JMenuItem text and accelerator alignment in right to left orientation

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I'm using right to left menus in a Java application.
I used this on all `JMenuBar`,`JMenu` & `JMenuItem` elements to make them right to left:

```
jmenubar.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
jmenu1.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
jmenuitem1.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Now the problem is `JMenuItem`'s **text is aligned right correctly** but **its keyboard accelerator is misaligned** as this image shows (F2 & F3 are out of view and others are not aligned left):
[image: F2 & F3 are out of view and others are not aligned left]

**Question:** How can fix a right to left `JMenuItem`'s accelerator alignment?

---

For SSCCE:
This Code Produces the problem:

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        javax.swing.JFrame frame = new javax.swing.JFrame("test");
                        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    javax.swing.JMenuBar menubar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
                    javax.swing.JMenu jmenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu("\u0645\u0646\u0648");
                    javax.swing.JMenuItem jmenuitem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem("\u0645\u0646\u0648 \u06F1");
                    javax.swing.JMenuItem jmenuitem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem("\u0645\u0646\u0648 \u06F2");
                    javax.swing.JMenuItem jmenuitem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem("\u0645\u0646\u0648 \u06F3");
                    javax.swing.JMenuItem jmenuitem4 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem("\u0645\u0646\u0648 \u06F4");
                    jmenuitem1.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0));
                    jmenuitem2.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F3, 0));
                    jmenuitem3.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_C, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK|java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
                    jmenuitem4.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_D, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
                    menubar.applyComponentOrientation(java.awt.ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                    jmenu1.applyComponentOrientation(java.awt.ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                    jmenuitem1.applyComponentOrientation(java.awt.ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                    jmenuitem2.applyComponentOrientation(java.awt.ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                    jmenuitem3.applyComponentOrientation(java.awt.ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                    jmenuitem4.applyComponentOrientation(java.awt.ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                    jmenu1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 15));
                    jmenuitem1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 15));
                    jmenuitem2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 15));
                    jmenuitem3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 15));
                    jmenuitem4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 15));

                    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
                    menubar.add(jmenu1);
                    jmenu1.add(jmenuitem1);
                    jmenu1.add(jmenuitem2);
                    jmenu1.add(jmenuitem3);
                    jmenu1.add(jmenuitem4);
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setSize(200,200);
                }
            });
        }catch(java.lang.Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might try `applyComponentOrientation()`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6475412/230513).

Comment: @trashgod: I tried; and same result!

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, but setting the accelerator in an `Action`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513), may be worth a try. To reach a broader audience, edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @trashgod: I added the code that produces problem.

Comment: thanks for the example - worksforme :-)