# Reading files in UTF-8 in any Windows OS

Tags: java, swing, utf-8, character-encoding

I am writing a string to a  file that has characters like Ԉ  and ف.

I want to specify the encoding as UTF-8 and hence I am forced to convert it to bytes, instead of writing as characters, either using `OutputStreamWriter` or `.getBytes("UTF-8")`.

I am able to save and read the file (and do a `sysout` in Eclipse console). Of course if I set the file encoding property in Eclipse as UTF-8, I do see my characters like Ԉ  and ف.

Now my question is, instead of printing these characters to my console if I pass it to a text field within my Swing application, will it still correctly display the characters? If I distribute my Swing application to another person in Europe (different Windows charset map), will it also correctly display the characters?

Comment: See also this related [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6475320/230513).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be fine.  AFAIK, the Java APIs for displaying text in a Swing API are not sensitive to the native OS default character encoding / map.

Comment: +1 agreed but quite be ignored onWindowsXP with Full Language Localizations pack

Comment: @mKorbel - I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @mKorbel - I still don't understand you.