# How to insert text right to left in to JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield, right-to-left

I'm creating small game for children to teach maths.For that I need `JTextField` to operate right to left. It mean that If I type "A" then "B" using keyboard, in `JTextField` it should be display like "BA". I think you guys can get a idea now.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the orientation of JTextArea from right to left (inside JOptionPane)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475320/how-to-set-the-orientation-of-jtextarea-from-right-to-left-inside-joptionpane)

Comment: textField.setCaretPosition(0); Try this

Answer (score 7):

Use `setComponentOrientation` method of **JTextComponent Class**

```
textField.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Comment: Actually this is not what I want.I want to type text reverse. :)  any Help?

Comment: If I type  "A" then "B" then "C"  in textfield it should display like "CBA"

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is not a feature of JTextfield or its parents.

One way you can get what you want is to use Apache Commons Lang library and class StringUtils.reverse("flip") -> "pilf".

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#reverse-java.lang.String-