# How can I align the text in JTextArea in java gui swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

How can I align the text in the textarea in java swing , is there a property for this and how ?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work out:

```
JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();
jTextArea.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

(credit to Braj for this answer).

Also, this should give you more information: [How to set the orientation of JTextArea from right to left (inside JOptionPane)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475320/how-to-set-the-orientation-of-jtextarea-from-right-to-left-inside-joptionpane)