# how to set JtextArea focus in right position?

Tags: java, jtextarea, right-to-left, setfocus

when i enable or request focus in text area the focus or caret anything u name it, it located at left. but when i start typing, it change to right. 
please help me to make it on right when request focus(true); 
this is the properties of textarea:

```
textManualIn = new JTextArea();
textManualIn.setLocale(new Locale("ar", "AE"));
textManualIn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(5, 22));
textManualIn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5, 22));
textManualIn.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
textManualIn.setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);
textManualIn.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));
textManualIn.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);
textManualIn.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
textManualIn.setSelectionColor(new Color(153, 255, 255));
textManualIn.setMargin(new Insets(2, 5, 2, 5));
textManualIn.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
textManualIn.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
textManualIn.setCaretColor(Color.BLACK);
textManualIn.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
mainmanual.add(status);//add to Jpanel
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475320/how-to-set-the-orientation-of-jtextarea-from-right-to-left-inside-joptionpane

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475320/how-to-set-the-orientation-of-jtextarea-from-right-to-left-inside-joptionpanethat only set the comp. orientation, but focus of caret still in left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not perfect, but you can try this code:

```
textManualIn.setText(" "); // one space
// And use one of the following
textManualIn.setCaretPosition(0);
// -or-
textManualIn.select(0, 1);
```

Comment: it lil tricky, but work. thanks. btw user didn't know. lol +1

Comment: Which one did you use - `setCaretPosition` or `select`?

Comment: set caret position(0), cause after text has space" " , the caret move to right, if i use select (0,1),  when edit text it return some error.

Comment: Its not a problem to have a space in front of the text?

Comment: no problem, cause set to (0), and i use space for span either. i made arabic trasliterator. it work good.

Comment: finally get this done,give whitespace setText(" "); then setCaretPosition(1); reset with setText("");